# Non-existent 0d LED debug code AX 370 Motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, desktop-computer, computer-building, amd-ryzen

Putting together my first PC, just got everything hooked up and running into my first errors. When the computer starts up, I get two LED debug codes: `Pre-memory North-Bridge initialization is started`, followed by `PCH PEI initialization`.

After it gets through those, it stops on a debug code `0d`. Now, that error code doesn't appear in the debug guide, but a similar `D0` code stands for `CPU initialization error`.

My set up is an AX370 Motherboard with a Ryzen 7 1800X, two GTX 1080s, an 850MW power source, 16gb RAM, and a corsair H100i V2 cooling system. All fans turn on, and the only error light on the motherboard is the CPU.

Having trouble finding any relevant information. Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: [AX370-Gaming 5 LCD Error Code 0d](http://forum.gigabyte.us/thread/891/ax370-gaming-lcd-error-code)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem in DavidPostill's link. This issue was caused by a RAM speed issues. Using the Ryzen 1800X and RAM with a 3k Mhz speed, resulted in this code.

I bought some slower RAM, swapped it out, and it seems to be running now.

http://forum.gigabyte.us/thread/891/ax370-gaming-lcd-error-code